# Is there a way to make 2 strings(such as two time strings like "4:00" and "5:00") comparable?

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, data-structures

I want to be able to compare 2 time string like:

```
"4:00" > "5:00"
```

and, of course, this should return false.

Is there a way to be able to map or assign these strings with  values in a linear manner( like "5:00 "should have a higher value than "4:00")? **No specific date is involved.**

The way I could somewhat make this work is manually put this inside a typescript enum, which automatically adds incrementing values

```
enum time {
"01:00",
"02:00",..
}

console.log("Value is: "+time["01:00"])
console.log("Value is: "+time["02:00"])
```

which returns:

```
Value is: 0
Value is: 1
```

But this method only works on pre-defined times. In the example above, time("04:21") will not work.

Comment: Hi @Warsea, is there a specific format for the string that you are comparing?

Comment: Indeed, yes. The format is "hh:mm". Like, as in the question, "04:37". The number ranges from "8:00"(which is 8 am) to "7:00" (which is 7pm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**Update** -- with the new requirement that, say, 7:00 means PM and 8:00 means AM, we need a normalization stronger than just `padStart`.  The old version of this answer is below.  Here we update by adding a `normalize` function.)

You won't be able to use `<` like that.  JavaScript does not have any sort of operator overloading.  But you can write a function that does this.  For instance:

```js
const normalize = (time, [h, m] = time .split (':') .map (Number)) =>
  String ((h < 8 ? h + 12 : h) || 12) .padStart (2, '0') + ':' + m
  
const compareTimes = (a, b, x = normalize (a), y = normalize (b)) =>
  x < y ? 'less than' : x > y ? 'greater than' : 'equal'

console .log (compareTimes ('4:00', '5:00'))   //=> "less than"
console .log (compareTimes ('10:15', '5:30'))  //=> "less than"
console .log (compareTimes ('2:00', '11:000')) //=> "greater than"
console .log (compareTimes ('9:30', '09:30'))  //=> "equal"
```

We include a `normalize` function that turns times into `hh:mm` format, with times in the `00:00` - `07:59` range into PM versions, using a little bit of math on the hour, and keeping other times intact, except to add a leading `0` when necessary.

The important thing to note here is that `"10:15"` compares as greater than `"5:30"`, even though the strings compare the other way.

A variant of this is much more useful.  Instead of `"less than"`, `"greater than"`, and `"equal"`, we could use `-1`, `+1`, and `0`.  This is used in most C-style languages, including JS, for sorting purposes.  So if we rewrote like this:

```js
const compareTimes = (a, b, x = a .padStart (5, '0'), y = b .padStart (5, '0')) =>
  x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0
```

we get a standard comparator we can use is [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and elsewhere:

```js
const normalize = (time, [h, m] = time .split (':') .map (Number)) =>
  String ((h < 8 ? h + 12 : h) || 12) .padStart (2, '0') + ':' + m

const compareTimes = (a, b, x = normalize (a), y = normalize (b)) =>
  x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0

const times = ['10:00', '9:15', '4:00', '5:00', '4:21', '7:32', '11:59']

console .log (times .sort (compareTimes))
//=> ["4:00", "4:21", "5:00", "9:15", "10:00", "11:59", "7:32"]
```

And we might want to turn that into a function which doesn't modify the original array but returns a new sorted one.  That's a trivial addition:

```js
const normalize = (time, [h, m] = time .split (':') .map (Number)) =>
  String ((h < 8 ? h + 12 : h) || 12) .padStart (2, '0') + ':' + m
  
const compareTimes = (a, b, x = normalize (a), y = normalize (b)) =>
  x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0

const sortTimes = (times) => [...times] .sort (compareTimes)

const times = ['10:00', '9:15', '4:00', '5:00', '4:21', '7:32', '11:59']

console .log ('Sorted:', sortTimes (times)) 
//=> ["4:00", "4:21", "5:00", "9:15", "10:00", "11:59", "7:32"]

console .log ('Original is not modified: ', times)
//=> ['10:00', '9:15', '4:00', '5:00', '4:21', '7:32', '11:59']
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

### Old version

<del>You won't be able to use `<` like that.  JavaScript does not have any sort of operator overloading.  But you can write a function that does this.  For instance:</del>

```js
const compareTimes = (a, b, x = a .padStart (5, '0'), y = b .padStart (5, '0')) =>
  x < y ? 'less than' : x > y ? 'greater than' : 'equal'

console .log (compareTimes ('4:00', '5:00'))  //=> "less than"
console .log (compareTimes ('10:15', '5:30')) //=> "greater than"
console .log (compareTimes ('9:30', '09:30')) //=> "equal"
```

<del>The important thing to note here is that `"10:15"` compares as greater than `"5:30"`, even though the strings compare the other way.</del>

<del>A variant of this is much more useful.  Instead of `"less than"`, `"greater than"`, and `"equal"`, we could use `-1`, `+1`, and `0`.  This is used in most C-style languages, including JS, for sorting purposes.  So if we rewrote like this:</del>

```
const compareTimes = (a, b, x = a .padStart (5, '0'), y = b .padStart (5, '0')) =>
  x  y ? 1 : 0
```

<del>we get a standard comparator we can use is [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and elsewhere:</del>

```js
const compareTimes = (a, b, x = a .padStart (5, '0'), y = b .padStart (5, '0')) =>
  x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0

const times = ['10:00', '9:15', '4:00', '5:00', '4:21', '17:32', '11:59']

console .log (times .sort (compareTimes))
//=> ["4:00", "4:21", "5:00", "9:15", "10:00", "11:59", "17:32"]
```

<del>And we might want to turn that into a function which doesn't modify the original array but returns a new sorted one.  That's a trivial addition:</del>

```js
const compareTimes = (a, b, x = a .padStart (5, '0'), y = b .padStart (5, '0')) =>
  x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0

const sortTimes = (times) => [...times] .sort (compareTimes)

const times = ['10:00', '9:15', '4:00', '5:00', '4:21', '17:32', '11:59']

console .log ('Sorted:', sortTimes (times)) 
//=> ["4:00", "4:21", "5:00", "9:15", "10:00", "11:59", "17:32"]

console .log ('Original is not modified: ', times)
//=> ['10:00', '9:15', '4:00', '5:00', '4:21', '17:32', '11:59']
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Added an update for the new requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Create them as dates, and compare.

```js
const timeA = '4:21';
const timeB = '05:00';

new Date(`2000-01-01 ${timeA}`).getTime() > new Date(`2000-01-01 ${timeB}`).getTime();
```

Comment: I suppose this is the safest bet. Issue is that the time isn't in 24hour format. The time  is within a range of "8:00"(which is 8 am) to "7:00" (which is 7pm). I guess I'll find a way to logically determine this am/pm thing.

Answer (score 0):

String comparison should work here.

```
"4:00" > "5:00" // would yield false
```

Comment: How about "4:00" > "05:00" ?

Comment: @Yogi It's only valid for the specific example given, obviously this is about the general case and this answer falls down with examples like `"5:00" > "12:00"`

Comment: Unfortunately, as mentioned by others, this solution doesn't give the desired output in many circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a fixed format for your string, I think you can always split the string into hour part and minute part, then compare the hour first followed by the minute.

To compare the hour part in the range 8 (am) to 7 (pm), we may simply offset it by +4 then mod 12, just like the way our hour system jump back from 11 to 0 suddenly.

Sample code

```
function isAfter(time1, time2) {

  var time1Arr = time1.split(":");
  var time2Arr = time2.split(":");
  var hour1 = parseInt(time1Arr[0]);
  var minute1 = parseInt(time1Arr[1]);
  var hour2 = parseInt(time2Arr[0]);
  var minute2 = parseInt(time2Arr[1]);
  var hour1Offset = (hour1 + 4) % 12;
  var hour2Offset = (hour2 + 4) % 12;
  
  if (hour1Offset === hour2Offset) return minute1 > minute2;
  return hour1Offset > hour2Offset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to your specification that 8-12 is in the AM range and 0-7 is in the PM range:

Since JS does not allow operator overloading, we cannot use >, <, or = directly, but we can define a function which returns -1, 0, or 1 for each of the respective cases (or modify for true/false for each operator, though that is left out).

```
/**
 * @brief Normalizes time to an hour minute object in 24-hour time
 * @condition the time is between 8AM and 7PM
 */
function normalizeTime(time: string) {
  if(typeof time !== "string" || !/\d{1,2}:\d{2}/.test(time)) // Test whether the time is a string and whether it is in the correct format
    throw new Error("Invalid Time Format"); // TODO: implement correct time handling
  let [hour, minute] = time.split(":").map(str => parseInt(str));
  if(hour < 8) {
    hour += 12;
  }
  if(hour > 24 || hour < 0 || minute > 59 || minute < 0)
    throw new Error("Invalid Time (hours or minutes out of bounds)"); // TODO: implement correct time handling
  return {
    hour,
    minute
  };
}
  
/**
 * @brief Compares two time strings in the format H?H:MM, with the time range 8AM-7PM
 * @returns -1 if timeA is before timeB, 1 if timeA is after timeB, and 0 if timeA is at the same time as timeB
 */
function compareTimes(timeA: string, timeB: string): -1 | 0 | 1 {
  const timeAN = normalizeTime(timeA);
  const timeBN = normalizeTime(timeB);
  if(timeAN.hour === timeBN.hour && timeAN.minute === timeBN.minute)
    return 0;
  if(timeAN.hour > timeBN.hour || (timeAN.hour == timeBN.hour && timeAN.minute > timeBN.minute))
    return 1;
  return -1;
}
```

```js
/**
 * @brief Normalizes time to an hour minute object in 24-hour time
 */
function normalizeTime(time) {
  if(typeof time !== "string" || !/\d{1,2}:\d{2}/.test(time)) // Test whether the time is a string and whether it is in the correct format
    throw new Error("Invalid Time Format"); // TODO: implement correct time handling
  let [hour, minute] = time.split(":").map(str => parseInt(str));
  if(hour < 8) {
    hour += 12;
  }
  if(hour > 24 || hour < 0 || minute > 59 || minute < 0)
    throw new Error("Invalid Time (hours or minutes out of bounds)"); // TODO: implement correct time handling
  return {
    hour,
    minute
  };
}
  
/**
 * @brief Compares two time strings in the format H?H:MM, with the time range 8AM-7PM
 * @returns -1 if timeA is before timeB, 1 if timeA is after timeB, and 0 if timeA is at the same time as timeB
 */
function compareTimes(timeA, timeB) {
  timeA = normalizeTime(timeA);
  timeB = normalizeTime(timeB);
  if(timeA.hour === timeB.hour && timeA.minute === timeB.minute)
    return 0;
  if(timeA.hour > timeB.hour || (timeA.hour == timeB.hour && timeA.minute > timeB.minute))
    return 1;
  return -1;
}

console.log(compareTimes("4:31", "0:30"));
console.log(compareTimes("4:31", "1:30"));
console.log(compareTimes("4:31", "4:30"));
console.log(compareTimes("4:31", "5:30"));
console.log(compareTimes("4:31", "4:32"));
console.log(compareTimes("4:31", "10:30"));
console.log(compareTimes("4:31", "12:30"));
console.log(compareTimes("4:31", "4:31"));

const inputA = $( "input#inpA" );
const inputB = $( "input#inpB" );
const result = $( "#result" );
$( "#comp" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
  try {
  console.log(inputA.val());
    result.text("Result: " + ["<", "=", ">"][compareTimes(inputA.val(), inputB.val()) + 1]);
  } catch (e) {
    result.text("Invalid Time Strings: " + e);
    throw e;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Time A:</label><input id="inpA" /> <br />
<label>Time B:</label><input id="inpB" /> <br />
<button id="comp">Compare</button>
<p id="result">
```